# Cannot get selected index of tab control of another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I run my application in differents threads, actually for get the selected index I do this:

```
int index = -1;
Head2Head.Head2HeadTbc.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { index = Head2Head.Head2HeadTbc.SelectedIndex; });
```

essentially `Head2Head` is the name of user control, and `Head2HeadTbc` is the TabControl.
I added a breakpoint on the last line and I get

> System.InvalidOperationException on all properties of `Head2HeadTbc`, and the index value is even -1, how can I solve this?

Image example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGRZH.png)

Comment: Should you not use: Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => ...

Comment: @Sjips what? I doesn't have any CurrentDispatcher method

Comment: Sorry, i meant: this.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => ...

Comment: @Sjips I also doesn't have this